# Javascript Overriding issue

Tags: javascript

I struck up in a Javascript method overriding problem for a while. the problem is i got onclick event handler on one of my controls and i need to to do inject some method before the event handler triggers the actual method.

assume DGrid.Headerclik is actuall assigned to onclick event.

And this is what i did

```
  DGrid.Headerclik  = handleinLocal;
```

so whenever user clicks the grid now the control comes to handleinLocal method. here i have to do some processing and then call the base Headerclik().

```
  function handleinLocal(){
      // here i need to call the DGrid.Headerclik() method (base)
  }
```

but this is not working as expected. on calling the DGrid.Headerclik()  within the handleinLocal() recursively calls the handleinLocal() method. But i need to call the base method...

is there a way to achieve theis in JavaScript??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the previous handler in a (closure) variable:

```
(function() {
   var oldHandler = DGrid.Headerclik;

   DGrid.Headerclik = handleInLocal;

   function handleInLocal() {
      // ...
      oldHandler();
      // ...
   }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Save the original callback in a variable before you reassign it your own handler.  Then after you have done what you need to do, invoke the original handler from the variable.

```
var callback = DGrid.Headerclik;
DGrid.Headerclik = handleinLocal;

function handleinLocal()
{
     ...your code...
     callback();  // invoke original handler
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the original click event handler to a variable then in your new click event handler, call the original click handler

```
var oldOnClick = DGrid.Headerclik || function() {};

DGrid.Headerclik = handleinLocal;

function handleinLocal() {
   // Do what you need to do
   oldOnClick();         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys (all) for your reply.. your method is elegant.. this successfully calls the base method,  i forgot tell u one morething, DGrid is a sepearate function got its own methods & properties. And i got one more problem here..

DGrid.Headerclik() iself uses 'this' operator to access the methods & properties from its scope.. so on calling the oldHandler() it runs within my local. not exactly in the DGrid scope. (this operator only returns the properies of my page not in the DGrid )

to avoid this i assigned the oldHandler  back to the DGrid.Headerclik and calls DGrid.Headerclik () directly..

```
var oldHandler = DGrid.Headerclik;   
DGrid.Headerclik = handleInLocal;
function handleInLocal(sColumnIdx){
    FormColumnWidthJSONArray();
    //OldHandler(sColumnIdx)    
     DGrid.Headerclik= OldSCCHandler;
    DGrid.Headerclik(sColumnIdx) // To Call the actual Column Click handler in DGrid;
    DGrid.Headerclik= HandleLocal;
}
```

Comment: Looks like your call to `DGrid.Headerclick` seems to be doing a DOM call so you might be suffering from the dreaded DOM Livequery syndrome.  I could be wrong though

Comment: guys am not answering my own question, i just wanted to type precisely, thats y am using the answer option..  why stack doesnt have  a reply option with neat text support ..?? this one i really hate...